# How do I access a variable from a class then use it in another class for my if statement in c#?

Tags: c#

Im a complete beginner to C# and trying to make a project by learning class. But Im stuck with this problem. I'm trying to pass a variable from this class

```
class UserAccount
{
    decimal balance = 0;
    public void PrintBalance()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYour balance is: {0}", balance);
    }
    
}
```

to another class and want to use it in my if statement and possibly edit the variable **balance**

```
class UserInterface
{
    public UserInterface()
    {
        UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount();

        Console.WriteLine("~~~Welcome to ATM Service~~~");
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease select from the following:\n");
        Console.WriteLine("[1] Check Balance");
        Console.WriteLine("[2] Withdraw Cash");
        Console.WriteLine("[3] Deposit Cash");
        Console.WriteLine("[4] Quit ATM Service");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        int userChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (userChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                userAccount.PrintBalance();
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Enter amount you wish to withdraw.");
                int withdrawAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if(withdrawAmount <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Amount must not be negative number or 0.");
                    break;
                }
                if(withdrawAmount < userAccount.balance)
                {

                }
```

I'm stuck with userAccount.balance in the if statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make `balance` a public property which can then be initialised. Also, by convention, properties have an initial capital letter,

Comment: Also, where are you setting the actual `UserAccount` values for a customer?

Comment: you mean by property is the get & set? am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to access a member from outside of a `Class` you have to use the proper **access modifier**.

In a simple way, you have to use as per below:

```
public decimal balance = 0;
```

Although it is not wrong, another approach is to use `Property Members` inside a class:

```
public decimal Balance { get; set; }
```

For more information and a better understanding of different access modifiers you may visit the following reference:

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I'm also curious because 1 comment here says to use the {get; set; }. What are their differences if we use the get set and if we dont use?

Comment: there is a number of benefits to using properties, yet it is not possible to describe all here in a single comment. the important one is that you can use property setters/getters to apply the logic that a mere public field can't. You google it, I'm sure there are a lot of exciting topics you can find to read and learn. Cheers.

Comment: When I first encountered setters/getters I had no idea where to use it. Now I know and will read regarding this. Thank you so much for your advice and clarifications.

Comment: You may also read this topic too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property

Answer (score 0):

By default, in C#, visibility for a class property like your `balance` is set to `private`. You have to make it `public` to access it from an instance of the class.

```cs
public decimal Balance { get; set; } = 0;
```

Advices :

1. 0 is already de default value for `decimal` type in C# so you don't have to set it.
2. In C#, generally, we use PascalCase for public properties/methods.
3. A getter/setter (`{ get; set; }`) is generally better for public properties.

Comment: thank you so much. I'd also like to clarify because there is also 1 answer here too that he didn't use the { get; set; }. What are their differences if we dont use them?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an access modifier the compiler set it as private by default.
Class variables should always be private.
You can use Properties or methods to access them.

```
private decimal balance;
```

by Propertie

```
public decimal Balance
{
    return balance;
}
```

by Method

```
public decimal getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}
```